# New member guide and other learning resources for US Congress

Tags: united-states, congress

Is there a place where new members go to learn how Congress works on the floor? Also, is there a guide or series of guides that can explain how debating works, and how scheduling items for debate works?

Comment: What do you mean by new members?

Comment: Like a newly elected person

Comment: I would assume that they are assumed to have either studied the process during a law/politics degree or by being a junior member helping someone else who is a member of Congress and learning from experience/through them. Otherwise they may pick up a mentor. With the basics down they can probably look up the legal procedures to get more detailed information. Though I don't really know, just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

There's an orientation process for new members of Congress. For instance, in 2018 it was hosted in Cambridge, MA by the Harvard Kennedy School's Institute of Politics, you can read about it in this [Harvard Crimson article.](https://www.thecrimson.com/article/2018/12/7/2018-congress-freshman-orientation/)

There's also an online [New Member Resource Center](https://www.congressfoundation.org/congressional-operations/new-member-resource-center), although much of this seems to be more relevant for staff of the Congress members than the members themselves. This is not surprising, since staff handle most of the detailed tasks of running a congressional office, the members mainly deal with politics and legislation. This resource is actually provided by an organization called Congressional Management Foundation, not Congress itself. They also provide training programs for Congress members and their staff.